# Failing to search polygons that intersect with other polygons with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-php

In our app, ES holds objects with areas field, where areas field in a type of MultiPyligon. (basically, it's an array of polygons).

Now, we need to search for all the objects in which one of their polygons in at least partially falls within a given polygon (in our case it is the current viewport of the map).

The current query that we are experimenting with is the following:

```
$params = [
            'index' => self::CrimeIndex,
            'body' => [
                'size' => 10000,
                'query' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'filter' => [
                            'geo_bounding_box' => [
                                'areas' => [
                                    "top_left" => [
                                        "lat" => $neLat,
                                        "lon" => $neLng
                                    ],
                                    "bottom_right" => [
                                        "lat" => $swLat,
                                        "lon" => $swLng
                                    ]
                                ],
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
];
```

The problem is that this query gets all the polygons that touch the edges of the bounding box. (see picture). How can we get all the polygons that are at least partially within the bounding box?

[image]

Mappings are done as follows:

```
$params = [
    'index' => CrimeService::CrimeIndex,
    'body' => [
        "mappings" => [
            'properties' => [
                'areas' => [
                    'type' => 'geo_shape'
                ]
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
$client->indices()->create($params);
```

Based on the docs, `geo_shape` can be `MultiPolygon`.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html

And here is the example of how it looks like populated:

[image]

`GET crimes/_mapping/field/areas` provides the following:
[image]

---

**UPDATE - More Detailed Steps to reproduce**

The dump of the collection/index is attached: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8inavsvcrnuozw1/dump-2021-12-29t21_54_04.639z.json.zip?dl=0

The query that is executed with elasticsearch-php is:

```
$params = [
            'index' => 'crime',
            'body' => [
                'size' => 10000,
                'query' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'filter' => [
                            'geo_bounding_box' => [
                                'areas' => [
                                    "top_left" => [
                                        "lat" => $neLat,
                                        "lon" => $neLng
                                    ],
                                    "bottom_right" => [
                                        "lat" => $swLat,
                                        "lon" => $swLng
                                    ]
                                ],
                            ]
                        ],
                    ]
                ]
            ],
        ];
```

If we execute it with the parameters:
`49.29366604017385,-123.00491857934166,49.19709977562233,-123.26617317321401`

We get the following:
[image]

In case that the viewport is changed a bit, so the polygons touch the borders of viewport: `49.28031011582358,-122.92300503734472,49.18371770837152,-123.18425963121705`,
we get the rest of the polygons:
[image]

Comment: Very strange, as the `geo_bounding_box` query should handle intersection out of the box. Have you tried a `geo_shape` query with `relation: intersects` instead?

Comment: @Val We did, but that didn't work at all. Maybe because that PHP library does not support it? I am not sure how to convert this query object to use relation...

Comment: Which version of ES are you using? And are you sure that the PHP client is compatible with that version?

Comment: It's 7.15.2 . Seem to be working for everything else.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "touch the edges", though

Comment: In other words, if the searchable polygons are fully contained within the viewport, they are not part of the result set. If at least one point is touching the borders of the bounding box, then they are.

Comment: Wow, that's very unusual... Anything worth mentioning about your mapping? Was the index created with an older version and then upgraded to 7.15.2?

Comment: Nope, everything is under the same version. We even deleted everything and reindexed all the data from scratch.

Comment: So, if you move the viewport slightly to the bottom, the missing polygon will appear?

Comment: Yep :) Exactly!

Comment: Do you mind sharing the mapping definition of your `areas` `geo_shape` field?

Comment: Absolutely, added into the post.

Comment: In addition can you run this `GET crimes/_mapping/field/areas` and update your question with the output please?

Comment: Done, updated. see above.

Comment: Really weird, I can't reproduce it. I have a geo_shape and I can retrieve it with a bounding box that either fully contains it or not 

Comment: hmmm... And how does your request look like? Same as ours?

Comment: Exact same query, nothing fancy, just a `geo_bounding_box` constraint. Anyway I could reproduce with your specific polygon? Can you gist a reproducible case for me to try?

Comment: Do you mean the code itself? Or the data too? I definitely can, but tomorrow (it's almost 2am :) )

Comment: Just an export of the problematic shape and the exact query you're running. No worries, tomorrow is fine too

Comment: @Val Instead of gist, I added more details about the issue. There isn't much to create gist out of.

Comment: Thank you. The polygons in the export are not in the Vancouver area, though, right? https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8Puj.jpg

Comment: Moreover, I think you have your query coordinates wrong, the points you gave are bottom_left/top_right, instead of top_left/bottom_right: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0ka9.jpg
I think that explains the problem

Answer (score 1):

Your query coordinates are wrong, instead of top_left + bottom_right, you have bottom_left + top_right (see image below)

[image]

I think that pretty much explains why you're seeing what you're seeing.